# Is it possible to run Windows Telnet in linemode?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, telnet

(originally posted to Stack Overflow - erroneously)

I can change Mac's mode to either line or character with the mode command, but here is no "mode" command in Windows telnet, at least in WinXP.

Does anyone know a way to open Windows Telnet Client in line mode, or how to switch it to line mode while running?

Answer (score 3):

Line mode is not directly supported in my windows 10 version of telnet.
How I do this:

- Run cmd as Administrator, to enable Telnet run this:

  `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`
- Activate your telnet connection as you usually do:

  ```
  telnet 127.0.0.1 port
  ```
- Escape the console via CTRL+], confirm `?` gives you a list of commands.
- `sen LINE` will allow you to send a line instead of just characters.

Answer (score 2):

Open `telnet` and type `set mode ?` it should get you a list of what's supported. My current installation has a different language but the supported modes would be along the lines of "console" and "datastream". You'd have to test of either of those are applicable for you.

If they're not, you might not be able to use the built in `telnet` client. You could have a look at [putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) in that case. I'm not certain it supports what you need but it does have a lot more options.